# Are there FP names for operator that pipes an operation into innermost structure ? (similar to the |> operator in fsharp)

Tags: f#, functional-programming, operators, higher-order-functions

I had to write 2 operators :

```
let inline (|/>) (seqinit:seq<'a*'T>) f = seqinit |> Seq.map  (fun (key1 ,seq1) -> (key1, seq1 |> f ))
let inline (||>) (seqinit:seq<'a * seq<'b>>) (f2:seq<'b>->seq<'c*seq<'d>>) = seqinit |>  Seq.map  (fun (key1 ,seq1) -> (key1, seq1 |> f2 ))
```

In order to have the following operations, the first group transforming Seq's to Map's, the second group adding a key to a collection

```
let toMap  (seqinit:seq<'a*'T>)                 =  seqinit |/> id     |> Map.ofSeq  
let toMap2 (seqinit:seq<'a*seq<'b*'T>>)         =  seqinit |/> toMap  |> toMap
let toMap3 (seqinit:seq<'a*seq<'b*seq<'c*'T>>>) =  seqinit |/> toMap2 |> toMap


let groupBy2 f1 f2 (seqinit:seq<'a>) = 
  seqinit |> Seq.groupBy f1  ||> (Seq.groupBy f2)

let groupBy3 f1 f2 f3 (seqinit:seq<'a>) =
  seqinit |> Seq.groupBy f1  ||> (Seq.groupBy f2) ||> (Seq.groupBy f3)
```

Are there any special name for those 2 operators |/> and ||> ?

This would help me find other such operators and not reinvent the wheel

EDIT

it is also useful for ungrouping

```
let ungroup  (seqinit:seq<'a*seq<'b>>)                 = seqinit |> Seq.fold(fun state (key, keyseq) -> Seq.append state keyseq) Seq.empty
let ungroup2 (seqinit:seq<'a*seq<'b*seq<'c>>>)         = seqinit |/> ungroup |> ungroup
let ungroup3 (seqinit:seq<'a*seq<'b*seq<'c*seq<'d>>>>) = seqinit |/> ungroup |/> ungroup |> ungroup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`||>` is already defined in FSharp.Core as `'T1 * 'T2 -> ('T1 -> 'T2 -> 'U) -> 'U`. Usage: `(arg1, arg2) ||> func`. Its compiled name is `op_PipeRight2`.

Your definition of `|/>` seems too customized to be of general use, so my guess is there isn't a predefined name for it.

Comment: thanks. I guess the general use would be to define operation like cast and melt in R, which are very useful functions when it comes to grouping data.